# The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?' not !0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this part of my query in EF

Status is byte.

i try `parameters.Status.Value != 0`
but for me it does not solve because 0 is a value that is on the table

the way it is below it shows the error:
`The result of the expression is always 'true' since the value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'`

```
if (parameters.Status.Value != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Status== parameters.Status);
            }

            try
            {

                return query
                    .Sort(parameters, x => x.Id)
                    .Paginate(parameters);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new Exception(this.context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, exception);
            }
```

In my view 
if the user does not select any value it should not pass this condition if

obs .: no value selected it is null.
how to make this validation without taking the 0 table?

Comment: MAybe you should simply check for `parameters.Status.Value != 0` instead of `null`?

Comment: That the input parameter nullable like 'int? status'

Comment: Please show the code for the class that `parameters` is an instance of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the correct format to check if it has value or not

```
if (parameters.Status.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Status== parameters.Status.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the type of `parameters.Status` is really `byte?`, because [`byte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx) doesn't have a .Value property.

If so then check `parameters.Status != null` and later use `x.Status == parameters.Status.Value`

The `.Value` of a nullable type converts the value to the non-nullable version (or blows up if it was a null). So that .Value can itself never be null.

The line compiles (with a warning) because that byte value of Status.Value is silently converted (back) to a nullable byte so that the null-check makes some sense.

Comment: parameters.Status is a byte

Comment: @OAprendiz If it's a `byte` then it wouldn't have a `Value` property.